# Node webkit opening a new window and listening for on.loaded

Tags: javascript, node.js, window, node-webkit

OK so I couldn't find an answer for this one, I am trying to open a window, execute a command once it's loaded, and then modify it's DOM from the main window.
Here's my sample code:

```
var window = window.open('empty.html',{
    "position": "center",
    "focus": true,
    "toolbar": false,
    "frame": true
  });
...
window.on("loaded",function() {
...
```

It doesn't fire. when I tried

```
var a_window = window.open('empty.html',{
  "position": "center",
  "focus": true,
  "toolbar": false,
  "frame": true
});
a_window = gui.Window.get(a_window);
...
a_window.on("loaded",function() {
...
```

but here it doesn't even open the window! (No I don't have a hide() function inside the callback) also, no error is thrown. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try and see if this shouldn't do the trick, it did for me:

```
var a_window = window.open('empty.html',{
  "position": "center",
  "focus": true,
  "toolbar": false,
  "frame": true
});
onload = function() {
    alert('Help it\'s loaded!');
};
```

Just so you know, I think the onload triggers for every window, so remember to unset it when you don't need it:

```
onload = null;
```

You can also try this for the individual window:

```
a_window.onload = function() {
    alert('Help it\'s loaded!');
};
```

Comment: If you want to know why the other thing doesn't work, I think it is because you can't set dependencies once the window is created or something. :)

Comment: This is a really bad hack I know, and it just triggers on the first window refresh, so yeah, but at least it something. I will report back if I ever find a proper solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

`nw.Window.open` callsback the third argument with the opened window.
`nw.Window.get` takes the DOM window as an argument.

```
nw.Window.open('empty.html',{},win=>win.on('loaded', () =>someFunction(nw.Window.get(win.window))));
```